# Is there any program which I can use to train custom tactics puzzles?

Tags: software, tactics, puzzles, pgn

Essentially, I would like to have the following features/workflow:

1. I obtain a `.pgn` file with (puzzle) positions and moves (the solutions)
2. I load that `.pgn` into the program and then solve (sequentially) the puzzles, with an interface similar to the lichess.org or chess.com tactics trainer

Of course some options might be nice (i.e. sequntial vs. random order, hints that are generated by an engine in the background, some statistics etc.) but the above two things are essentially that.

Surprisingly I cannot find such a program, let it be open source or commercial. The only thing similar was an apparently abandoned freeware program dubbed *Chess Hero*, but that threw a lot of errors even with very simple `.pgn` files...

Answer (score 2):

[Lucas Chess](https://lucaschess.pythonanywhere.com/) can do what you're asking for. I use it myself to train custom tactics pgns on my computer.
Lucas Chess also supports managing pgn databases.

To create a custom tactics training:

> Databases: Tools/Databases create new, import PGN, Trainings, create ....

For mobile, you can use [Scid on the go](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.scid.android&hl=en&gl=US) which I also use myself.

Answer (score 1):

This [chess puzzle editor](https://www.apronus.com/chess/puzzle/editor.php) accepts one puzzle at a time in PGN format and creates a public link for an interactive puzzle. It has the following features:

- the computer replies even if the user goes wrong
- the computer tries multiple defenses before admitting success
- the user is allowed a choice of alternative solutions

The two last features need the PGN to include multiple defenses and alternative solutions.

Answer (score 1):

I have written a chess GUI called Nimzo_2023. It is a fork of the Tarrasch Chess GUI with some added features. One of the features that I added was puzzle mode,
which provides most of the puzzle features that you require.

I had not thought of random puzzle selection, I might add that. The program can be downloaded from the website - [Nimzo_2023 Chess GUI website](https://nimzo3chess.000webhostapp.com) or directly from the following link - [Nimzo_2023 Chess GUI Mediafire link](https://www.mediafire.com/file/e1560hk721loqx9/setup_Nimzo_chess.7z/file)

I based the puzzle mode on the one in the free ChessX program.  You could check that one out too.